# When I'm reviewing the close votes, let me see suggested dupes side by side

Tags: feature-request, review, close-dialog

So I'm reviewing a close vote that's a potential dupe. I click <kbd>close</kbd> and hit up the suggested dupe to see if it is a valid dupe. This is what I see:

[image: Worse than useless]

The modal completely obscures the original, and when I scroll it stays in place. Is there some way to display the dupe so that it doesn't obscure the original? When reviewing in particular, reading one question in full and remembering enough about it to compare with the dupe overlaid is too much effort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can drag that dialog:

[image: screenshot]